# JavaFx - End Dialog don't want to appear

Tags: java, multithreading, dialog, javafx, scene

I'm working on a game application which needs an end-game dialog.
I tried to do it a several ways, but couldn't reach to work.

My game algorithm's method runs on a separate thread.
After finishing the gameplay, in that thread i've tried to call (in the `GameScene`'s class) like `getChildren().add(endDialog)`, but nothing happened. If I added it in it's constructor and than in the gameplay-thread's end put `getChildren.get(0).toFront()`, still nothing happened.

Any suggestion?

**EDIT**

Found a way that work, but it's not that perfect:

```
   setOnMouseMoved(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
            if(ended) {
                getChildren().add(new EndDialog());
                getChildren().get(25).setOpacity(0.7);
            }
        }
    });
```

Its only problem is that after I've finished playing, I have to move my mouse one more time in order the dialog to appear.

How should I catch in time the `ended` field's value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What kind of thread did you use ?

in JavaFX you have to Use the [Service](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html) classe to do the things correctly and don't make freez the GUI stuff.

On this service you have an onSucceeded field, so if you listen it you can do what you want when it have finished to work.

You can laso take a look a [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm)

And if you want nice dialogs take a look at [ControlFX](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/features/)

Comment: I agree with [agonist_](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1737321/agonist) above. Although there is no mention of [Task](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) or [Service](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html), but to do all thread operations you should use one of these in a JavaFX application.

Comment: The major difference being that with [Service](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html), you can talk to the JavaFX application thread, which would not be possible with the [Task](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) API.